# What server technology uses phdo extension?

Tags: webserver

I've seen some websites using the .phdo extension.
I googled for it, but I've found no conclusive result.

Is it a proper technology or just a synonym of .php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only pattern I could find with this extension is websites based on Pheedo technology, and the Pheedo website seems to be written in PHP.

So it may be the Pheedo platform that uses this .phdo extension